# What is the difference between linear interpolation mode and vector mode in Graph Editor?

Tags: graph-editor

I am following some online tutorials for basic Blender animation. Over there, I have found that there are two ways to convert the default bezier curve line to straight line. We select the keyframe animation, before the following.

The first method is pressing "V" key (to enter keyframe handle type menu) and selecting vector.

The second method is right clicking and selecting the interpolation mode to linear.

Is there a difference in the result of the two methods? To my untrained eye the end result looks basically the same.

Comment: it won't make any difference for the animation but with V > Vector you're still able to manipulate the handles, I guess that's all

Comment: Linear is an interpolation from current frame to the next, while Vector is a Handle Type [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html)